# How to find if a javascript is already loaded or not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing a chrome extension to ajaxify every non ajax website like wikipedia. etc. It works fine but it fail to load the js files. So, I have written a script to load js files thats are required for the page by getting src attribute from  tag. But the problem is when i am loading another page of that website every scripts are loaded again. So it is useless to make it with a purpose to reduce bandwidth.

So, I want to know whether there is any way to match the script array of the new with its previous page. and to identify which scripts are new and load only them.

```js
var array1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jsn; i++) {
    var jssrc = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[i].src;
    array1.push(jssrc);
}

var array2 =  [how to find out array script source of the new page]
Array.prototype.diff = function(array2) {
    var ret = [];
    for(i in this) {
        if(array2.indexOf( this[i] ) > -1){
            ret.push( this[i] );
        }
    }
    return ret;
}; 

ajaxpagefetcher.load("ajax-script", "", true, array1.diff(array2);)
```

How to find script src array of the new page that is to be loaded..
one more question, with out reloading the page if i delete the body tag through remove() function, are the scripts that already loaded also removed? 
Thanks
I am waiting with eager for your replay....

Comment: So, you only want array2 to contain script src's not in array1?

Comment: not that, i want to put array of script src's of the page that is to be loaded. in Array2 but  Array1 contains script src's array of the page from where i perform ajax request to load the page.

Comment: Don't pollute `Array.prototype`. Don't iterate arrays with `for...in` loops.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the JS file:

```
window.iAmLoadedOnThisWindow = true;
```

And in the loader part:

```
if(! window.iAmLoadedOnThisWindow) {
    // append the script with some dom method
}
```

If the JS file is a library, test the library : `if(jQuery)`, `if(_)`, etc.